# React dynamic props with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, types

I want to implement a TimePicker component with react&typescript .. my code works fine but typescript has some errors. if I pass range:false prop then value prop can be string(something like '10:30') and if I pass range:true then value prop should be array of string(something like ['10:30','11:30']).

```
type SingleTime = {
  value: string;
  onChange: (val: string) => void;
  range: false;
};
type RangeTime = {
  value: string[];
  onChange: (val: string[]) => void;
  range: true;
};
type TimePickerProps = {
  min?: null | string;
  max?: null | string;
};
type FinalProps =
  | (TimePickerProps & SingleTime)
  | (TimePickerProps & RangeTime);

export default function TimePicker({
  value,
  onChange,
  range = false,
  min = null,
  max = null,
}: FinalProps) {
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(!range) onChange('10:30') //Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & string[]'.
    else onChange(['10:30','11:30']) //Error: Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & string[]'

  },[range,onChange])
  return (<div></div>);
}
```

Comment: Since you destruct the props, the relation between them is lost. A possible solution is doing as in [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nda4Xm). Does this approach work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It works ... but I really want to destruct props ... Is there no way around it beside not desturcting the props ?

Comment: Maybe there is, but I can't think of anything and you can still destruct the common props, such as `min` and `max`